# Packet forwarding in HSR?

Tags: redundancy

Does a node forward a packet further, even if the destination node is itself?

Comment: What do you mean? A unicast frame is sent, possibly replicated to all interfaces in the case of an unknown unicast, and if the end host is on the network, it reads the frame (other hosts receiving the frame will ignore it). The frame only exists as it is sent on the wire to be received (or ignored). otherwise it doesn't exist. It is not "removed."

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. HSR (High-availability Seamless Redundancy) requires a ring topology and every node passes the packet to the next one until packet reaches to the destination (and twice by design). My question is, does the destination node forward the packet further so packet travels to the source node back (twice) and source node has to remove the packet it injected earlier.

Comment: If a node receive the same frame twice, it simply doesn't forward the second one, and the destination doesn't forward the frame. There is nothing that "removes" the frame. The frame only exists as it is being sent, and when it is no longer sent, it simply ceases to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A node will not forward the same frame a second time.

The destination node will not forward the frame.

Those two situations prevent the frame from being forwarded forever.

Comment: Does this behaviour referred as "Mode U"?

Comment: That would be true for a unicast frame, about which you originally asked, destined only to that node.